# Weird behavior of java.util.Set.contains(Object o)

Tags: java, set, equals, contains

The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) about `java.util.Set.contains(Object o)` says:

> Returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that
>   (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

That said, here is a POJO (as you can see, I overwrote its `equals` method):

```
public class MonthAndDay {

    private int month;
    private int day;

    public MonthAndDay(int month, int day) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        MonthAndDay monthAndDay = (MonthAndDay) obj;
        return monthAndDay.month == month && monthAndDay.day == day;
    }

}
```

So please, why does the following code prints `false` instead of `true`?

```
Set<MonthAndDay> set = new HashSet<MonthAndDay>();
set.add(new MonthAndDay(5, 1));
System.out.println(set.contains(new MonthAndDay(5, 1)));
// prints false
```

A solution is to rewrite the `contains(Object o)` method, but the original one should be (almost) exactly the same, am I wrong?

```
Set<MonthAndDay> set = new HashSet<MonthAndDay>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        MonthAndDay monthAndDay = (MonthAndDay) obj;
        for (MonthAndDay mad : this) {
            if (mad.equals(monthAndDay)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

};
set.add(new MonthAndDay(5, 1));
System.out.println(set.contains(new MonthAndDay(5, 1)));
// prints true
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you override `equals(Object)` you also need to override `hashcode()`.

Specifically, the methods must be implemented so that if `a.equals(b)` is `true`, then `a.hashcode() == b.hashcode()` is all `true`.  If this invariant is not respected, then `HashMap`, `HashSet` and `Hashtable` will not work properly.

The technical details of how `hashcode()` and `equals(Object)` should behave are specified in the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) API.

---

So why do the hash-based data structures break if you get this wrong?  Well basically because a hash table works by using the value of the hash function to narrow down the set of values to be compared with the "candidate".  If the hashcode for the candidate is different to the hashcode for some object in the table, then the chances are that the lookup algorithm won't compare with the object in the table ... even if the objects are equal.

Comment: So in my case, what do you think of an `hashCode()` that returns `month * 100 + day`?

Comment: It should work just fine.  For technical reasons, it would be slightly better if `100` was replaced by a prime number (e.g. 31).  However, it is not going to make much difference.

Answer (score 7):

`HashSet` will only use `equals()` *if* the elements share the same `hashCode()`, thus you need to override both. [Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html)'s the relevant part of the code that is used by [`HashSet#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) (note that `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`):

```
  355       /**
  356        * Returns the entry associated with the specified key in the
  357        * HashMap.  Returns null if the HashMap contains no mapping
  358        * for the key.
  359        */
  360       final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
  361           int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
  362           for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
  363                e != null;
  364                e = e.next) {
  365               Object k;
  366               if (e.hash == hash &&
  367                   ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
  368                   return e;
  369           }
  370           return null;
  371       }
```

Not doing so, violates the contract of [`Object#hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), which states that:

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then
>   calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Comment: Actually HashSet uses `equals()` to compare elements which have the same `hashCode()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You're right, I was actually reading your blog's post last night when you discussed something similar : ). I've edited my answer.

Comment: So in my case, what do you think of an `hashCode()` that returns `month * 100 + day`?

Comment: Yes, that uniquely identifies each `MonthAndDay` object. `HashMap` (and `HashSet`) will then rehash your provided `hashCode()` in an attempt to *ensure* a good enough distribution. Take a look here (http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ313_029.htm) for Joshua Block's suggestion for implementing `hashCode`s.