# Strange behaviour when comparing objects with hashCode and equals

Tags: java, oop, collections

I wanted to override `equals` in a way that two objects should be considered equal if they are implementing the same interface (BaseProduct) and all their fields are equal.

While testing these methods I have noticed an interesting behaviour: if both `groceryProduct` and `techProduct` have `List<Reviews> reviews` field set to `null` and other fields are equal, comparing hashCodes and `equals` method return true.

However if the two objects have a list of reviews passed to a constructor(the last argument in the example below), both comparing returned hashCodes and an `equals` method return false.
When debugging the code I have seen that `groceryProduct` and `techProduct` indeed have different hashCode values.

I wonder what could cause such a behaviour?

I have intentionally compared the `reviews` field in the `equals` method with Objects.deepEquals() hoping that it could solve the problem. But it did not help.

```
GroceryProduct groceryProduct = groceryProductFactory.create("Bonanza", "Bananas", new BigDecimal(45),
            1500, 200, Arrays.asList(new Review("A1", 10)));
TechProduct techProduct = techProductFactory.create("Bonanza", "Bananas", new BigDecimal(45),
            1500, 200, Arrays.asList(new Review("A1", 10)));

// Both print false for the example above 
// True only if the last argument reviews list is null
System.out.println(groceryProduct.hashCode() == techProduct.hashCode());
System.out.println(groceryProduct.equals(techProduct));

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof BaseProduct)) return false;
        BaseProduct that = (BaseProduct) o;
        return totalQuantity == that.getTotalQuantity() &&
                defectiveQuantity == that.getDefectiveQuantity() &&
                Objects.equals(brand, that.getBrand()) &&
                Objects.equals(productName, that.getProductName()) &&
                Objects.equals(price, that.getPrice()) &&
                Objects.deepEquals(reviews, that.getReviews());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(brand, productName, price, totalQuantity, defectiveQuantity, reviews);
```

Comment: Did you override `hashCode` and `equals` for `Review` class as well?

Comment: Just a rephrasing of the @tsolakp comment.  You must override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods for the `Review` class.

Comment: @tsolakp You are right. That did the trick. By the way, do you consider using Objects.deepEquals(reviews, that.getReviews()) method appropriate in the situation?

Comment: Just note that `hashCode` doesn't return `true` or `false`, it returns an `int`. You should be more precise about your question.

Comment: You can safely use `Objects.equals`. The `Objects.deepEquals` does not give you any advantage since your `reviews` are List and not an Array.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer Sure hashCode returns an `int`. `True` was returned when comparing the two ints like in the example above `System.out.println(groceryProduct.hashCode() == techProduct.hashCode());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird behavior of java.util.Set.contains(Object o)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249277/weird-behavior-of-java-util-set-containsobject-o)

Comment: @user1803551 **No it's not.** In the possible dupe the answer is `When you override equals(Object) you also need to override hashcode().` But here I have overridden both methods!! I know that it's important to override both. No reason to downvote my question if you haven't read it carefully!

Comment: No, you didn't override them, otherwise you wouldn't have had this problem. You also said your self that overriding them fixed it. If you want a closer duplicate then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697407/arraylist-remove-is-not-removing-an-object) one works too. I downvoted because for lack of research which is essential for a good question.

Comment: @user1803551 My problem was about comparing complex objects. It was not about overriding both `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of comparing objects. Object comparison is done by `equals` (which means you also need `hashCode`). The complexity is irrelevant. An object equals another one i.f.f `equals` returns `true` on their comparison. What `equals` checks for is up to the developer. The fact that an instance inside the objects you are comparing is not the same only recursively applies the rules to that instance's type. it's exactly the same.

Comment: Show the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for the `Review` class.

Comment: @user1803551 that is why I asked the question. I have missed the fact that it is important to compare instances inside the objects. However I was aware of the importance overriding `hashCode` and `equals` simultaneousely.

Comment: @Bohemian There were none, that's the point of the question. After they were implemented the OP reported that it works.

Comment: @user1803551 it was a rhetorical question

Comment: @user1803551 It was not about `should I implement hashCode and equals simultaneousely?` It was about how to compare complex objects properly.

Comment: And the answer is: by implementing `equals` (and `hashCode`), which is the answer you find on this site if you search.